How to automate resolving circular dependencies between definitions and obligations in Coq?
The answer to this question suggests to use the sequence set (x := foo_obligation_n _ _ ... _). clearbody x. simpl in x. before destruct foo. to remove the circular dependency between foo and foo_obligation_n.
Since I frequently work with dependent types (e.g., in this project), I would like to streamline this process with a tactic.
Is there an existing tactic to automatically resolve this type of dependency, or is there a way to automate the described sequence of tactics?

I wouldn't call this a “circularity problem”. It is not essentially linked to Program obligations. You would have the same problem if you wrote the proof by hand in Gallina without Program.

This kind of circularity is due to program, but also in big part to your particular definition, and I don't know how to do deal with that automatically.
However, looking at the file you linked, as an alternative, it seems that you could avoid circularity all together by using a different definition of nth_safe that would be as easy to reason on.
You could instead define nth_safe and similar functions inductively, getting rid of your dependencies.
Require Import List Lia.
Import ListNotations.


Program Fixpoint nth_safe {A} (l: list A) (n: nat) (IN: n < length l) : A :=
  match l,n with
  | a::l, 0 => a
  | a::l, S n => nth_safe l n _
  | [], _ => _
  end.
Next Obligation. cbn in *. lia. Defined.
Next Obligation. cbn in *. lia. Defined.

Lemma nth_safe_nth: forall A (l: list A) (n: nat) d (IN: (n < length l)%nat), nth_safe l n IN = nth n l d.
Proof.
  intros A l. induction l; intros n d IN; destruct n; cbn in *.
  - lia.
  - lia.
  - reflexivity.
  - apply IHl.
Qed.
```

